# Python ctypes - Accessing data string in Structure .value fails

Tags: python, ctypes, structure

I am able to get a Structure populated as a result of a dll-function (as it seems looking into it using `x=buffer(MyData)` and then `repr(str(buffer(x)))`.

But an error is raised if I try to access the elements of the Structure using `.value`.

I have a VarDefs.h that requires a struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  char Var1[8+1];
  char Var2[11+1];
  char Var3[3+1];
...
}TMyData
```

that should be passed to a function like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int AFunction(TOtherData *OtherData, TMyData *MyData);
```

In Python I am now able to declare the structure this way (thanks to Mr. Martelli: see here [Python ctypes - dll function accepting structures crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488173/python-ctypes-dll-function-accepting-structures-crashes) ):

```
class TMyData( Structure ):

    _fields_ = [
        ("Var1" , type( create_string_buffer(9) ) ),
        ("Var2" , type( create_string_buffer(12)) ),
...
```

I call the function this way: `result =  Afunction( byref(OtherData) , byref(MyData ) )`

As said, as I try to access `MyData.Var1.value` I get an error (sorry, can't be more specific now!), but `repr(str(x))` where x is a copy of `buffer(MyData)` shows that there are data in it!

How should I do it instead? Thanks!

Comment: I see several things potentially wrong here, but it's pretty difficult to help you out with essentially "it doesn't work" as the problem.

Comment: BTW, my previous comment wasn't intended as a passive-aggressive snark, but a request for a more exact error or stack trace :-).

Answer (score 3):

The structure you're trying to use ctypes to interface with contains a several "arrays of characters" not "pointers to arrays of characters". Rather than using `create_string_buffer(9)` you'll need to use `ctypes.c_char * 9`.

```
class TMyData( ctypes.Structure ):
   _fields_ = [ ("Var1", ctypes.c_char * 9),
                ("Var2", ctypes.c_char * 12), ... ]
```

Comment: That bit of his code is certainly unidiomatic and more convoluted than necessary, but Python reports `(ctypes.c_char * 9) is type(ctypes.create_string_buffer(9))` as `True`, so that's not the poster's (primary) problem.

Comment: It's not unidiomatic.  That's the way to declare an array in ctypes.

Comment: @Mark I was saying the original poster's code was unidiomatic, not Rakis's correction.

Comment: @llasram: my bad, I didn't read "that bit of _his_ code" close enough :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `print MyData.Var1`.  The character array is converted to a Python string type when accessed through a `Structure` instance, which doesn't have  a `.value` method.

Contrived, working example:

#### DLL Code (x.c, compiled with MSVC with "cl /LD x.c")

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char Var1[5];
    char Var2[10];
    char Var3[15];
} TMyData;

__declspec(dllexport) int AFunction(TMyData *MyData)
{
    strcpy(MyData->Var1,"four");
    strcpy(MyData->Var2,"--nine---");
    strcpy(MyData->Var3,"---fourteen---");
    return 3;
}
```

#### Python Code

```
import ctypes as c

class TMyData(c.Structure):
   _fields_ = [
        ("Var1", c.c_char * 5),
        ("Var2", c.c_char * 10),
        ("Var3", c.c_char * 15)]

lib = c.CDLL('x')
data = TMyData()
lib.AFunction(c.byref(data))

print data.Var1
print data.Var2
print data.Var3
print data.Var1.value # error!
```

#### Output

```
four
--nine---
---fourteen---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 436, in ImportFile
    my_reload(sys.modules[modName])
  File "C:\x.py", line 12, in <module>
    print data.Var1.value
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I got muddled, but on attribute access `Structure` instances automatically convert values of any basic type into the corresponding Python type.  Normal `ctypes` character arrays definitely do have `value` attributes, so you should probably update your answer to prevent confusion.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'll fix it.